# How can i efficiently query a table entry that matches either of words from Set in moor

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, flutter-moor

I have a Set of String that contains words . The the Set can be of length 15 in average.
Am wondering if i can query the entries that contains either these words with moor's operand | efficiently without having to loop the Set like i have done here.

```
Future<List<Upload>> search(Set keys, List<Upload> result) async { 
keys.forEach( (term) => (select(uploads)..where((tbl) => tbl.title.contains(term))) .get() .then((value) => result.addAll(value)), ); 
return SomeResult;
}
```

I can see that am running a single query multiple times.
Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I somehow found the solution here for anyone looking for same scenario
https://moor.simonbinder.eu/docs/getting-started/expressions/#in-and-not-in using .isIn list

```
Future<List<Upload>> search(List keys)  => (select(uploads)..where((tbl) => tbl.title.isIn(keys))).get();
```